# when using android studio to create a new project, the error happened

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

```
Failed to import Gradle project: Could not fetch model of type 'IdeaProject' using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'.
A problem occurred configuring project ':aaa'.
A problem occurred configuring project ':aaa'.
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':aaa:classpath'.
Could not download artifact 'com.google.guava:guava:13.0.1@jar'
Could not download artifact 'com.google.guava:guava:13.0.1@jar'
Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 1891110; received: 1693112

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Maybe if you try again. Sounds like internet connection issue

Comment: from your Command/Terminal try the `gradlew compileDebug --stacktrace` from your project path and see if you see any more detailed logs. but it does look like the gradle-1.6-bin.zip is corrupt, I had that happen once and had to delete the local partially downloaded file.